# Web app for ArcGIS Enterprise step by step for user

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-enterprise

I've seen webmaps that show the steps to help user to navigate the application.

Does anyone know what widget can I use to implement this feature on ArcGIS Enterprise WebMaps?

I have ArcGIS 10.7.1 license